# Something like Include for HTML in VS2010 at build time

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to split a single HTML page (purely static, HTML + JS) in VS2010 (I use VS2010 + ReSharper for my HTML /Js coding) into parts, but get / build a single page at **build time**.

There was such a feature with Dreamweaver (I have used this years back, think it called libraries). If I was using PHP I'd use something like Include at **runtime**.

My page contains several `div` sections serving as tabs, only one visible at time. I want to place the code between these tabs in a single file, to make it easier to maintain. But in the end I do need **one single, static HTML file**. Again, I want to do this a **build time**, **not at server side**.

```
<DIV>
  many lines of HTML
</DIV>
```

should be replaced by something like

```
<DIV>
  #include tab1.html
</DIV>
```

I could write a script building the static page and hook it into VS2010, but is there some extension or function already existing?

-- Follow ups on using T4 ---

1. [VS2010 - Assign html code formatting to T4 (.tt) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355639/vs2010-assign-html-code-formatting-to-t4-tt-file)
2. [VS2010 - disable validation for particular html file (not all files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359804/vs2010-disable-validation-for-particular-html-file-not-all-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this question while searching for something else. You've probably moved on, but what the heck, maybe the answer will help someone else:

You could get so-called T4 templates to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Alternately, Microsoft has similar capabilities in Razor, and it's more specific to HTML.

Here is a comparison of the two:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2011/03/11/t4-vs-razor-what-s-the-skinny.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot updating this one!