# VS2010 - Assign html code formatting to T4 (.tt) file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

I am having a T4 text template (.tt) in VS2010 - mainly used to generate HTML code (basically some includes and JavaScript).

**Is it possible to assign the HTML code formatting** (colors, etc) to that tt file.

Is situation (the T4):

[image: How the tt file is formatted]

Want have:

[image: Can i get this formatting on a .tt file]

-- Update as of answer Marcio Barcellos --

Formatting with proposed AddOn:

[image: Formatting with AddOn]

Comment: This is perhaps a case for Razor as it's intended for HTML output. I have no experience however on hosting Razor in a non-ASP solution but it might be possible.

Comment: Is RAZOR for runtime or design time templates? I need design time templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extension to visual studio and get the result you want

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/40a887aa-f3be-40ec-a85d-37044b239591

Comment: This is an excellent extension. However, the formatting only works on code within template tags <#! !#> , not the html code on the outer level. See screenshot above.